# jQuery modal dialog and jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, modal-dialog, confirmation

How can I use the Jquery modal confirmation with jqGrid? Say when I will submit my entries it will pop up a modal dialog and display the names with the message for sending to server..

My approach

```
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            autoOpen:false,
            resizable:false,
            height:180,
            modal:true,
            buttons:{
                 'Confirm': function(){
                            var ids =jQuery("#list10").jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow');
                                $.ajax({
                                  type: "POST",
                                  url: "url&names="+ids,
                                  data: JSON.stringify(ids), 
                                  dataType: "json"
                            });
                                },
                            'cancel': function(){
                                    $(this).dialog('close');
                                    }
        }
        });
        });
```

my html :

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Confirm">
        <p><span class="ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Are you sure want to cancel(or send this names)#names?</p>
    </div>
```

In that dialog box I need to send those names as well... but this approach will not give me the names from my grid which I selected to send it to server.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following code could do what you need

```
$("#wics").click( function(){
    var grid = jQuery("#list10");
    var ids = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow');
    if (ids.length>0) {
        var names = [];
        for (var i=0, il=ids.length; i < il; i++) {
            var name = grid.jqGrid('getCell', ids[i], 'Name');
            names.push(name);
        }
        //alert ("Names: " + names.join(", ") + "; ids: " + ids.join(", "));
        $("#names").html(names.join(", "));
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            height:280,
            modal:true,
            buttons:{
                'Cancel': function(){
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                },
                'Confirm': function(){
                    //alert("Confirm");
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url:  "/cpsb/unprocessedOrders.do",
                        data: { method: "releaseTowics",
                            orderNum: JSON.stringify(ids),
                            names: JSON.stringify(names)
                        },
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(msg){
                            alert(msg);
                        },
                        error: function(res, status, exeption) {
                            alert(res);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The exact solution of cause will depends on your requirement on the server side. You can try this (without ajax request) here http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DataToMultiSelect2.htm. Select some items and click "Get Selected" button.

Comment: @Oleg: How we can use jqGrid's default confirm dialog box ?

Comment: @ITppl: Try the following code: `$.jgrid.info_dialog("some title which could be <i>HTML</i> text", "some other <span style='color:red'>HTML</span> text", true);`. You can use an additional parameter for additional options: see [the source code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.common.js#L184-200)

Comment: `.info_dialog` is not populating at the center of the window like `select a row` modal. any way to do this?

Comment: @CJRamki: You can use options of `$.jgrid.info_dialog` (4-th parameter): `top`, `left`, `width`, `height` and other to specify posizion and size of the info dialog. Alternatively you can use jQuery UI Position to change position of the dialog directly after its creating. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20496020/315935).