# Get multiple selections from jqgrid using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, jqgrid

I've managed to setup jqgrid with a database and customise it a bit. I have a mysql database with 2500 customers. I want to use jquery to select a number of those customers (in the grid) via checkbox and send the selected ones an email, like a newsletter (something which i will handle after i tackle this one!:)

So basically i need an array or list of data which jqgrid produces i guess which i can put through a 'wile' loop or something like that to send mails.

I hope i made myself clear here!

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,
thefisherman

Answer (score 0):

Probably you will find the answer on your question in [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587480/jquery-modal-dialog-and-jqgrid/3588732#3588732). You can modify the `$.ajax` call which send ids of selected rows to the server corresponds your requirements.