# JQGrid: get multiple checked row values in JQGrid by post

Tags: php, javascript, database, jqgrid, checkbox

I have one JQGrid in my php file and I have placed inside one form . On submitting form, i just want the checked value from the JQGrid.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#list1").jqGrid({
            url:'revMemberJson.php',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            loadonce: true,
            // jsonReader: { repeatitems: false },
            colNames:['Name','Mobile'],
            colModel :[ 
                {name:'name', index:'name',width: 100,searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne','cn']}}, 
                {name:'mobile', index:'mobile',search: false,width: 120}
            ],
            pager: '#pager',
            rowNum: 5,
            rowList:[5,20,30],
            rownumbers: true,
            multiselect:true,
            sortname: 'id',
            sortorder: 'desc',
            viewrecords: true,
            height: 'auto',
            width: 420, 
            shrinkToFit: false,
            gridview: true,
            caption: 'Members'
        });
        jQuery("#list1").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});

    });

    var myGrid = $('#list1'),
    selRowId = myGrid.jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'selrow'),
    celValue = myGrid.jqGrid ('getCell', selRowId, 'mobile');

</script>
```

And I have used the following code to get the checked value , But All stuff are made in java script. But I have to get the values for updating the database. So i need to get the value by post.

Please provide me the methods..

Comment: I want to get checked name and mobile no on form submitting

Comment: @oleg I use your code for getting select all(check all option) in JQGrid. Now I require how to get the checked value from the JQGrid by post/get.

Comment: If you would like to post a message to my you should write a comment with `@Oleg` in one of my old answers. The above comment made no notification to me, so I found it occasionally.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should use

```
var selRowIds = myGrid.jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
```

insteda of

```
var selRowId = myGrid.jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'selrow');
```

to get the array with ids of selected rows. You can use `JSON.stringify(selRowIds)` or `selRowIds.join(',')` to convert array in the form which you can easy send to the server.

I think that you can find some additional information in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3588732/315935) (see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DataToMultiSelect2.htm)).

Comment: Thank you so much @Oleg . I see your demo which is so usefull.