# Iterate through the list and get checked checkbox id in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jqgrid

I have got id's of all the row which have check box in a variable.

```
var allIds = jQuery("#progAccessSearchResults").jqGrid("getDataIDs");
```

Now I have to iterate over this and get id's of only checked check boxes. I tried following code to get checked checkbox id.

```
var boxes = $(":checkbox:checked");
```

But it is not working. Help me out..!! I am new to javascript n jquery. So pls don't mind if it is a silly problem..!!

Answer (score 15):

You can use [.map](http://api.jquery.com/map) to find all IDs of checked checkboxes, using your existing selector:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="cb2" />
<input type="checkbox" id="cb3" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" id="cb4" />
<input type="checkbox" id="cb5" checked="checked" />
```

**Javascript:**

```
var checkedIds = $(":checkbox:checked").map(function() {
        return this.id;
    }).get();
```

Returns: `[ "cb3", "cb5" ]`

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Blade0rz/CPJKv/) is a fiddle for the above code.

Comment: is there anyway to do this with pure javascript?

Comment: @SyedRasheed Really you just need to replace the jQuery selector, which is as simple as `[].map.call(document.querySelectorAll("...criteria", ...);` - [jsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/5m3bka63/)

Answer (score 4):

try with loop `each` of `jquery`

```
$("input:checkbox").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);    
    if($this.is(":checked")){
        console.log($this.attr("id"));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this piece of code

```
var selected = new Array();
$('input:checked').each(function() {
    selected.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

And you get all checked check box id in `selected` array. Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K527b/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use first [:nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector to get `<td>` elements having checkboxs in the grid. Then you can use `>input:checked` selector to get all checked checkboxs. After you have jQuery object which contains the requested checkboxes you can use `.closest("tr.jqgrow")` to get rows having the checkboxes. The ids of the rows is what you need. You can use `$.map` to get all ids in the array. The full code will be

```js
$("#getIds").button().click(function () {
    var $checked = $grid.find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow>td:nth-child(" +
                   (iCol + 1) + ")>input:checked"),
        ids = $.map($checked.closest("tr.jqgrow"),
                    function (item) { return item.id; });
    alert("The list of rowids of the rows with checked chechboxs:\n" + ids.join());
});
```

where the index of the column with checkboxs `iCol` you can get using `getColumnIndexByName` function

```js
var getColumnIndexByName = function (grid, columnName) {
    var cm = grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", 'colModel'), i, l;
    for (i = 0, l = cm.length; i < l; i += 1) {
        if (cm[i].name === columnName) {
            return i; // return the index
        }
    }
    return -1;
};
```

which I frequently used in my old answers.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/GetIdsOfCheckboxes.htm) demonstrate the above code live.

Comment: Oleg -- Actually I want it like this. I have a dialog box which asks "Are you sure you want to delete ?". On clicking yes, I need to get id'd of checked check boxes and send it to a method in a list. Can you help me pls. I don't know anything about jquery/javascript but now assigned with work on this..

Comment: @Student: It's almost the same what my demo do. You can use [confirm](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp), [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) (like in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3588732/315935)). In any way you should make separate `$.ajax` call to send the data to your server method.