# how to set the position of error dialog of jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

i am using jqgrid and my js cod is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    var grid = jQuery("#grid");

    grid.jqGrid({
        url: '/Admin/GetUserForJQGrid',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'Post',
        cellsubmit: 'remote',
        cellurl: '/Admin/GridSave',

        //formatCell: emptyText,
        colNames: ['Id', 'Privileges', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'User Name', 'Password', 'Password Expiry', 'Type', 'Last Modified', 'Last Modified By', 'Created By', ''],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', key: true, hidden: true, editrules: { edithidden: true } },
            { name: 'Privileges', index: 'Privileges', width: "130", resizable: false, editable: false, align: 'center', formatter: formatLink, classes: 'not-editable-cell' },
            { name: 'FirstName', index: 'FirstName', align: "left", sorttype: 'text', resizable: true, editable: true, editrules: { required: true } },
            { name: 'LastName', index: 'LastName', align: "left", sorttype: 'text', resizable: true, editable: true, editrules: { required: true } },
            { name: 'UserName', index: 'UserName', align: "left", sorttype: 'text', resizable: true, editable: true, editrules: { required: true } },
            { name: 'Password', index: 'Password', align: "left", sorttype: 'text', resizable: true, editable: false, editrules: { required: true }, classes: 'not-editable-cell' },
            {
                name: 'Password_Expiry', index: 'Password_Expiry', align: "left", resizable: true, editable: true, editoptions: {
                    size: 20, dataInit: function (el) {
                        jQuery(el).datepicker({
                            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {

                                jQuery('input.hasDatepicker').removeClass("hasDatepicker")                               
                                return true;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            },


            {
                name: 'Type', width: "100", index: 'Type', sorttype: 'text', align: "left", resizable: true, editable: true, editrules: { required: true }, edittype: 'select', editoptions: {
                    value: {
                        'Normal': 'Normal',
                        'Sales': 'Sales',
                        'Admin': 'Admin',
                        'SuperAdmin': 'SuperAdmin'
                    },
                    dataEvents: [
                            {
                                type: 'change',
                                fn: function (e) {

                                    var row = jQuery(e.target).closest('tr.jqgrow');
                                    var rowId = row.attr('id');
                                    jQuery("#grid").saveRow(rowId, false, 'clientArray');
                                }
                            }
                    ]
                }
            },
            { name: 'Modified', index: 'Modified', sorttype: 'date', align: "left", resizable: true, editable: false, classes: 'not-editable-cell' },
            { name: 'ModifiedBy', index: 'ModifiedBy', sorttype: 'text', align: "left", resizable: true, editable: false, classes: 'not-editable-cell' },
            { name: 'CreatedBy', index: 'CreatedBy', sorttype: 'text', align: "left", resizable: true, editable: false, classes: 'not-editable-cell' },
            { name: 'Delete', index: 'Delete', width: 25, resizable: false, align: 'center', classes: 'not-editable-cell' }

        ],
        shrinkToFit: true,
        delete: true,

        pager: '#pager',
        height: '100%',
        width: "703",


        **afterSubmitCell: function (serverStatus, rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {

            var response = serverStatus.responseText;
            var rst = 'false';
            debugger;
            if (response == rst) {
                debugger;               

                return [false, "User Name Already Exist"];

            }
            else {

                return [true, ""];

            }
        },**



        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 50, 100],
        sortable: true,
        loadonce: false,
        ignoreCase: true,

        caption: 'Administration',

        search: false,

        del: true,
        cellEdit: true,
        hidegrid: false,
        viewrecords: true,
        gridComplete: function () {

            var ids = grid.jqGrid('getDataIDs');
            for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                var isDeleted = grid.jqGrid('getCell', ids[i], 'Delete');
                if (isDeleted != 'true') {
                    grid.jqGrid('setCell', ids[i], 'Delete', '<a href="#" onclick="deleteUser(' + ids[i] + ');"><img src="/Images/delete.png" alt="Delete Row" /></a>');
                }
                else {
                    grid.jqGrid('setCell', ids[i], 'Delete', ' ');
                }
            }
        }
    }

    );
```

see on the `aftercellsubmit` i am returning the false value and error message. this dialog box appears at the left of page (wrong position) i need this dialog box on the jqgrid. can anybody help me.... thanks in advance :)  and i also want to change the look of that dialog, i have tried `$("#info_id").css('background-image', 'url("/Scripts/jqueryui/smoothness/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png")');` in my page in document.ready event but its not working.

Comment: i will defiantly mark your answer if it works for me ...help me please

Comment: are you kidding me... i am talking about the default dialogbox.. which shows error, info, notification... jqgrid in build dialog box. how to set the position of that dialog box

Comment: cant u view class of that dialog and according to change css through jquery

Comment: @RKSharmaSharma: You describe that the default position of the error message is not good, but you don't rescribed which position you what to have.

Comment: i did just you said but its not working

Comment: i have also tried $("#info_id").css('background-image', 'url("/Scripts/jqueryui/smoothness/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png")');

Comment: By the way if you write a comment to your *own* question nobody will be informed about that. Instead of that you can write a comment under the answer to your *old* question. Then the person who write the answer will be informed about your comment. You can use syntax like "@Oleg" to inform specific person if multiple persons wrote comments here before.

Comment: sry ;) i will keep in mind this useful information..thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to add the code like

```js
setTimeout(function () {
    $("#info_dialog").css({
        left: "30px", // new left position of ERROR dialog
        top: "10px"   // new top position of ERROR dialog
    });
}, 50);
```

inside of `afterSubmitCell` callback (somewhere before the `return` statement). The `rowid` parameter of `afterSubmitCell` callback and [jQuery UI Position](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ErrorPositionOfCellEditing.htm) method provides you simple way to move error dialog under the row which are editing. You need just replace `css` used in the code above to `position`:

```js
setTimeout(function () {
    $("#info_dialog").position({
        of: $("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(rowid)),
        my: "top",
        at: "bottom"
    });
});
```

I didn't tested the code, but I hope it will work.

**UPDATED:** [The dummy demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ErrorPositionOfCellEditing.htm) (without any code on the server which really saves the data) demonstrates the usage of `$("#info_dialog").position({...})`. Just try to edit some cell and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the data. You will see error message **directly after the line** which you edited.

Comment: @RKSharmaSharma: You are welcome! To make the second working you need include jQuery UI. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ErrorPositionOfCellEditing.htm) demonstrates usage of `.position`. Just try to edit some cell in the first column and save it you will see the error message **after the edited row**.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest inspecting you page and getting the element id of the dialog container and setting it's css to you desired position.

**Update:**

That probably doesn't work because the '#info_id' doesn't exist yet. You should attach attach a listener to the "DOMSubtreeModified" event like

```
document.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", function (e) {
  if(e.target.id == 'info_id'){
    $('#info_id').css('your css info here');
   }

  }, false);
```

Be aware that `DOMSubtreeModified` is deprecated but if this is an internal tool and you are only using it in a very limited fashion it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: i have tried it to change the background but didn't works for me $("#info_id").css('background-image', 'url("/Scripts/jqueryui/smoothness/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png")');